# why is my redim preserve causing type mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add in control names from a userform into an array to be spat out into a msgbox at the end. `arrBlank` Fields is supposed to look at controls and see if they're blank or not. if they are, redim preserve each name and then keep looping through to find all blank fields.

```
    Dim icontrol As Control
    Dim arrBlankFields As Variant
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
```

'for loop

```
Case icontrol.Name Like "txt*"
    If icontrol.Value = "" Then
        ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(1 To UBound(arrBlankFields))
        arrBlankFields(x) = icontrol.Name
        x = x + 1
End If
```

'end loop

getting a type mismatch at `1 to UBound(arrBlankFields)`. I've also tried just doing `ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(x)` because it's just a 1-dimensional array, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you redim the array prior to the loop: `Redim arrBlankFields(1 to 1) As Variant`

Comment: @ScottCraner ok so that worked, but now getting a subscript out of range error on `arrBlankFields(x)` part of `arrBlankFields(x) = icontrol.Name`

Comment: make sure `x=1` prior to the loop also.

Comment: Or make your array start at `0` like a normal programmer.

Comment: @HackSlash that depends on what one is doing with the array later.  If the OP is going to load it into the sheet or compare it to an array bulk loaded from the sheet it is easier to maintain the 1 base.

Comment: @ScottCraner ok, added `x=1` before loop so it adds in the first value within the array, and the next value that fits the case statement is another `cmb` control, but I get the subscript out of range error, again

Comment: your redim preserve should be `ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(1 To x)` or `ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(1 To UBound(arrBlankFields)+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use arrays when you know the size ahead of time. Use a collection when you don't. You never have to `ReDim` an array ever again.

```
Dim icontrol As Control
Dim arrBlankFields As New Collection
Dim i As Long
```

'for loop

```
Case icontrol.Name Like "txt*"
    If icontrol.Value = "" Then            
        arrBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
    End If
```

'end loop

Additional reading here: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/

Comment: Good advice.  Maybe change the variable name from `arrBlankFields` though?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, a good reason to avoid Hungarian notation. The OP would need to rename the variable everywhere.

Comment: ok so this works, but it also adds in all of my blank controls multiple times (in this case like 6-8x) within the collection. Anything in my code that would be allowing duplicates?

Comment: You haven't shown the rest of your code so it's difficult to say...

Comment: @NidenK If my answer solved the question please click the green checkmark on the left to close this question. You can open a new question with the new problem, showing different parts of the code. The scope of the question should not change if it's answered.

Answer (score 1):

1º Break line all variables (no change nothing but is better)
2º You need define first your arrBlankFields size, like this (example, make for you):

```
ReDim arrBlankFields(1000) ' No need preserve before increment, in this moment
```

or sample for you

```
Set dbUser = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Usuários")
QntUsers = dbUser.Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim arrBlankFields(QntGrupoUsers2)
```

3º you need start of zero your array:

```
    On Error GoTo err_control    
    Dim icontrol As Control
    Dim arrBlankFields As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    x=0
    
    'Case icontrol.Name Like "txt*" ' error  ... no have end select 
        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
        ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(1 To UBound(arrBlankFields)) 'REMOVE THIS LINE FROM HERE.
            arrBlankFields(x) = icontrol.Name
            x = x + 1
    End If
    ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(x)

   Err_Control:
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & Chr(13) & "Error Description: " & 
   Err.Description
   End If
```

4º after you read and create your array, now you can do that, above.

Good Luck

Comment: You can tell by the `If` statements that he doesn't know how many elements will be included at runtime. It's counting `txt` named controls with no value. This will change based on how many controls are filled out by the user.

Comment: I do not know. What are you trying to do ? Does it have to do with Form Controls? I didn't look at your if  (you Case is wrong). Edited to insert err_control      What you do there is up to you! doubts put here